# Can webform manage two types of financing and correctly calculate the Tax-Deductible in the contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I created two line items with different "Tax-Deductible" option in financial type (one type with yes other with no) but its not calculated correct in contribution Non-deductible Amount field. Can webform manage it? What would be the correct way to create it?

[image: Sample Financial type with tax deductible]

It seems that it always assigns the value based on the type of financing assigned to the contribution page associated with the webform.

Comment: I dont think that is possible.

Comment: Yes it is - this is a bug. We've not run into it b/c our CDN Tax Receipts extension code only checks the Non-Deductible amount if a Contribution Amount is indeed of a Financial Type that is TaxDeductible (i.e. TaxReceiptable). How are you using this field?

Comment: Well, the idea is update the "Non-deductible Amount" value in contribution depending on the financial type based on whether a contact wants to deduct or not. Im my case the financial types are based on this

Comment: I don't understand "whether Contact wants to deduct or not"? That field in Core is meant for Charitable Tax Receipting purposes -> to calculate the Eligible Amount for on the Tax Receipt.

Comment: The problem is that the input is coming from a Webform. The final user chooses "yes" or "no" whether he/she wants to deduct the contribution and by choosing he/she determines which financial type is used (a deductible one for "yes" a non deductible one for "no".  So we need to be able to choose the correct financial type from the webform. The field "Non-deductible Amount" is updated with all financial types asociated with line items, but always take "tax-deductible" associated in contribution page / financial type but not with financial types asociated in line item.

Comment: What does user “chooses whether or not they want to deduct the Contribution” mean? Deduct from what?